# ERC20 tokens representing documents

Tags: erc-20

I need some fast advice, so whoever helps me ill be forever grateful.

I was wondering what would be the best way to make an app that allows users to buy ERC20 tokens and trade them amongst other users?

Let me provide an example of what it should be able to do?

- Allow user to buy my erc20 token with a form field value
- Allow user to send token balance to another address

Can somebody please provide me direction!

Comment: what do you mean by "buy my erc20 token with a form field value"? Do you mean they fill out a form and then when they submit it they buy the token? Or that there is some value (string?) attached to each token?

Comment: Yes...user enter amount of tokens they want and then references smart contract to purchase